# Would a Negative Vacuum energy lead to stronger curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

Let's assume the space itself (the vacuum) has a negative energy density  $T_{00} < 0$. For simplicity let's set  $T_{11} 
= T_{22} =T_{33} = 0$.

For a central mass (as the only mass in the whole universe), the solution of the field equations then can be calculated with the **inner** Schwarzschild-metric (as there is everywhere still a $T\neq0$).
Then the extension of this object should be infinite, the energy density approaching zero (from below zero). The space with this negative energy density would "vanish" (T00->-0) in the infinity instead of approaching the Minkowski space.
The gravity derived from that object would be **stronger** than derived from the outer Schwarzschild metric (Newtonian limit) and Newtons law.

Could therefore a negative vacuum energy density be an alternative to the dark matter paradigm?

This question has nothing to do with modified newton dynamics, MOND. MOND does not refer to general relativity. My question refers to general relativity and is an idea how a stronger gravity than the Newtonian limit could be derived out of general relativity, only with negative vacuum energy.

Comment: This wouldn’t be a Schwarzschild metric. It would be FLRW

Comment: This question would get more attention with a meaningful title.  If your question is related to others, you should link the related questions in the body text.

Comment: Updated: changed title, added that T11=T22=T33 shall be zero for simplicity. Therefore, its not the FLRW.

Comment: Are you suggesting that dark matter is merely stronger gravitation?  Good luck with that!  In any case, vacuum energy is more commonly discussed in the context of dark energy.  I think there is a clue there . . .

Answer (score -1):

There is already the MOND theory (Modified Newtonian dynamics ).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics

Comment: MOND is not the answer to my question. MOND ignores general relativity (& curvature of space time) while my question is related to curvature. I would like to try out a thought experiment how the MOND behavior can be derived from general relativity.

Comment: Updated the question: It has nothing to do with MOND.